# How to add a close button to a Qmenu?

Tags: qt, qt4, qt-creator

How to add a Close button on top on the below menu?

I want a close button like windows and below that i need the below mentioned A to D setup menus.
How to do this ?

```
void MyMenu::cppSlot()
    {
        xmenumain = new QMenu;
        xmenumain->
        xmenumain->addAction ( "A -> Setup" , this , SLOT (call_a()) );
        xmenumain->addAction ( "B -> Setup" , this , SLOT (call_b()) );
        xmenumain->addAction ( "C -> Setup" , this , SLOT (call_c()) );
        xmenumain->addAction ( "D -> Setup" , this , SLOT (call_d()) );
        xmenumain->popup( QCursor::pos() );
        //Change font and width
        xmenumain->setFont(QFont ("Courier", 10));
        xmenumain->setFixedWidth(250);
        //Colour setting
        QPalette palette=xmenumain->palette();
        palette.setColor(QPalette::Background, Qt::darkGray);
        xmenumain->setPalette(palette);

        //xmenumain->setAutoFillBackground(true);


        // Align the menu coordinates
        xmenumain->move(900,300);
        xmenumain->show();
        /*if(!(xmenumain->isEnabled()))
        {
            xmenumain->show();
        }*/
    }
```

Comment: What would it do, close the menu or close the application?

Comment: maybe you could use a `QPushButton` and then `QPushButton::setMenu`

Comment: it should close the menu

Comment: Why do you want a close button on QMenu? QMenu hides automaticly after loosing focus. You probably want to make something different than QMenu (toolbox?)

Answer (score 0):

First, create a `QWidgetAction`. Then create a button, set it up the way you want it, and add it to the `QWidgetAction` with `QWidgetAction::setDefaultWidget()`. Finally, add the QWidgetAction to your menu with `QMenu::AddAction()` (the overload that takes a `QAction`; `QWidgetAction` derives from `QAction`.)

Comment: This doesn't work. It creates a menu item with an invisible background. Unless there are more steps in "set it up the way you want it" that are more mischievous than just setText/setIcon.